# Are we showing non technical roles in Stack Overflow jobs now?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-jobs

I came across this job posting which was looking for a valet parking site manager. As far as I know, Stack Overflow Jobs was only for hiring tech roles.
And the role description says, Embedded developer.

https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/202185/children-s-hospital-colorado-valet-parking-site-healthpark-valet?med=clc

Has something changed or did this slip through the cracks and appear on the ads?

Comment: But they need to be a **FULL STACK** valet parking manager.

Comment: The list of requirements read as if they are looking for a new CEO instead of a site manager - consider a wage of 18$/hour for being **embedded** in a valet-parking-booth and **developing** communication skills with stressed & grumpy customers..

Comment: After @iLuvLogix comment I thought that the job was a about developing the embedded system for the parking lot... that sounds like a fun project imho

Comment: Low-budget startup.   You valet park cars for the 20-something CEO's father -- who owns the lot and seed funded the startup -- and he let's you write code when the lot isn't busy.

Comment: I foresee a new trend where flipping burgers, washing cars, or answering phones is combined with some vague programming task and called an unpaid internship.

Comment: @yivi Are we allowed to award bounties to comments?

Comment: actually `valet-parking` is the hot new javascript framework.  See related tag creation request.

Comment: Wanted: chef developer. Must be able to read recipes and cookbooks, use a knife and deploy full meals three times a day.

Comment: If it is a child hospital, you must first start with a regular hospital and then `fork()` it. Each hospital will then have its own parking lot on the stack, so the valet will need to check the `pid` before piping the cars to the proper process, while ensuring there's no race conditions present on the parking lot. Ambulances will however have ring 0 kernel level access and should pass through straight away. How is it _not_ a programmer job?

Answer (score 119, accepted):

I've flagged it with our customer support team. That listing was imported from an API customer and they appear to have it misconfigured to import non-developer jobs.

For info, if you come across this again, you can flag these yourself by clicking the ellipsis on the right hand side of the listing and clicking 'Report'. You can then fill in what's wrong in the resulting dialog.

[image: Report Job]

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know if something had changed. That's why I didn't report it.

Comment: Thank you for using MS Paint to draw on that image.  Made my day.  (Paint.NET is better.  It fills the missing gap between MS Paint and a Photoshop-like tool.)

Comment: @CubicleSoft I used Paint.NET, but I'm a developer and hand-drawn red circles are all I know :P

Comment: "How do you draw red circles on an image?" should be part of the developer survey.

Comment: @mfitzp Step 1:  Read the specification on the PNG file format.  Step 2:  Locate some punch cards.  This is gonna take a while.