# Job board showing "Property Manager" position?

Tags: discussion, support, stack-overflow-jobs

I found this job listing for a property manager on the SO job board:

https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/205853/property-manager-hays-us?so=p&pg=2&offset=15&r=true

From what I can tell there is nothing tech related about this job.  It seems like an odd fit for the StackOverflow job board...

Is SO now advertising for non-tech jobs?  If not, how did this end up on there?

Screen shot:
[image]

Comment: Looks like some of the other jobs on their company page might not be tech related, either. (Did not read more than their titles, I could be 100% wrong!) This is likely a company that misunderstood that the SO job site is for developer positions.

Comment: Oh is there no person between the job poster and the public facing site?  Though I have nothing to back this up i had assumed that job posters worked with some sort of SO agent.

Comment: AFAICT, there is a team that supports jobs, but they don't vet each and ever job ad made. Instead, they, (again AFAICT) guide the companies in how to better attract devs. This company does have dev jobs, so I think they just need a quick chat with the support team, who will likely see this post. (You can also "report" a job, using the `...` button under the apply button.)

Comment: We already advertised for a [parking valet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/374269/are-we-showing-non-technical-roles-in-stack-overflow-jobs-now) position. This seems like a step up.

Comment: Companies read how-to-post guides just like users read how-to-ask guides. Unsurprising.

Comment: As long as it’s managing properties on Java objects… *ba dum tssss*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're right, this listing shouldn't have been posted. I've gone ahead and reported it so that our support team can address it with the employer directly.

As Kendra mentioned in the comments, the best thing to do if you ever come across a listing like this is to report it:

[image: Reporting a job listing]

While we do engage with companies to provide relevant and high-quality listings, such listings do sometimes get published especially when we have some form of automation involved. Hence, we rely on feedback from the community and review every reported listing that comes in.

Thank you for flagging this!